# The meaning of atoms sign in protein structure

Tags: protein-structure

There are some atoms sign of protein structure in paper, like Nε2， Cε. I know this sign is for information about atoms position, but I don't know the exact meaning. The below is original words in paper, which is about structure of type3 copper proteins.  [image]

I need more information about this atom sign system.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "numbering" of the atoms in the amino acids. For this purpose, greek letters are used. This follows the convention that the Cα is the carbon atom next to the carboxylic group. Cβ is the next one and so on.
ε1 and ε2 mark the positions at the end of the ring, which are carbon and nitrogen.

See this picture (from [here](http://www.biology.arizona.edu/biochemistry/problem_sets/aa/Basic.html)), which shows all the positions in Histidine:

[image]

Comment: So here, ε1 is abbreviated as ε. Cε is same as Cε1.

Comment: @CharlieXiong Yes.

Comment: Examples and references for the atom names are here: https://bmrb.io/referenc/nomenclature/